# while read line stops after first iteration

Tags: bash, unix, loops, iteration

I am trying to execute a simple script to capture multiple server's details using `svmatch` on server names input from a file.

```
#!/bin/sh
while read line; do
svmatch $line
done < ~/svr_input;
```

The `svmatch` command works with no problem when executed as a stand along command.

Comment: Is it intentional that you're string-splitting and glob-expanding the lines read from the file, trimming trailing whitespace, and expanding backslash-escape sequences? If you don't want to do all those things, there are some additional changes called for.

Comment: To be more explicit: If you don't want to string-split and glob-expand the lines, make it `svmatch "$line"`. If you don't want to expand backslash-escape sequences in the input, make it `read -r`. If you don't want to strip trailing whitespace from the input, make it `while IFS= read`.

Answer (score 12):

Redirect your inner command's stdin from `/dev/null`:

```
svmatch $line </dev/null
```

Otherwise, svmatch is able to consume stdin (which, of course, is the list of remaining lines).

The other approach is to use a file descriptor other than the default of stdin:

```
#!/bin/sh
while IFS= read -r line <&3; do
  svmatch "$line"
done 3<svr_input
```

...if using bash rather than `/bin/sh`, you have some other options as well; for instance, bash 4.1 or newer can allocate a free file descriptor, rather than requiring a specific FD number to be hardcoded:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r -u "$fd_num" line; do
  do-something-with "$line"
done {fd_num}<svr_input
```

Comment: Excellent explanation and solution. I have a similar issue with a command inside the loop that consumed stdin. Your fd_num option fixed my problem (and teached me how to deal with similar problems on the future.